# react native show component when loading is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a big component that take time to load, I have many Images and when this component loads I have blank space, It is possible to show the component when it finished to load at 100%

I have read all docs on component https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html but nothing for that, 
If anyone have an idea how to do that, I really want to know

Comment: Have you looked at componentWillMount, load everything there, set state, then render will run.

Comment: @TomMillard Thanks for your reply, I just want to show my component when the rendering is finished (100%)

Comment: you can load all images you need in componentWillMount, using img.onload wait for that to complete then populate state and then render. Personally i would lazy load the img into the dom and not wait for them to load before rendering the component.

Comment: @TomMillard Thanks for your advice I'll try, in my case this is for a native app :)

Comment: @TomMillard I'll update you